# SQLAlchemy. How to use the mapper() without a primary key?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Snippet:

```
metadata = MetaData()
items_table = Table('stat_aliases', metadata,
                    Column('item_id', Integer),
                    Column('alias', String)
)
metadata.create_all(dst)

class Row(object):
    def __init__(self, item_id, alias):
        self.item_id = item_id
        self.alias = alias

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Row('%s','%s')>" % (self.item_id, self.alias)

mapper(Row, items_table)
```

gives an error message

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|Row|stat_aliases could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'stat_aliases'
```

The table should not contain a primary key. 
How to use the mapper() without a primary key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLAlchemy needs to know about a *primary key*, because it uses it to store it in it's [identity-map](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/glossary.html#term-identity-map). If a `Table` don't have a *primary key*, SQLAlchemy has no safe way to distinguish two object mapped to this `Table`.

### Regarding your specific problem

My guess is that you want to have multiple `alias` entries per `item_id`. If this is the case, just mark both columns as `primary_key` (perhaps with `autoincrement` set to `False`).

This is called a [composite primary key](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html).